# Create duplicate web project in eclipse from WAR

Tags: java, eclipse

I can't seem to get this to work. I have created a project using the standard method in Eclipse. I have another working project from which I created a WAR file. I want to create a duplicate project, so that I can style the UI differently from the other one and have the back-end work the same way as the previous project and compare.

I have tried [this](http://agile.csc.ncsu.edu/SEMaterials/tutorials/import_export/) (importing from an archive file) method and [this](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wst.webtools.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Ftwimpwar.html) one (importing from a WAR file) and no cigar.
The second method gives me this error:

> A project already exists with this name.

I am sure I am doing something wrong, but am at a loss as to what. Thanks for any ideas in the mean time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried `importing from a WAR file` option and it works perfectly. When you reach the following screen (see screenshot below), you have to give another name to the clone in the `Web project:` field and Eclipse will create a new project on workspace.
[image]

Comment: This is helpful! However, I obviously do not see the java files from the parent project. Do I just manually add them within the generated folder structure?

Comment: I figured it out as being "yes" to my own question.

Comment: I think you mean the Java source files. As you know a war file does not contain any Java source files. The Java `.class` files contained in the WEB-INF/classes folder are imported and you'll find them under `/new_project_name/Java Resources/Libraries/Web App Libraries/ImportedClasses`. The rest of the web content is to find under the usual folder: `WebCotent`. If you want to add the Java sourcess into the newly created project, you have to copy them manually under `/new_project_name/src` folder. If you want to create a war file from this new project: right click on the project and export.